# MongoDB match document's array element based on condition defined in the element's value

Tags: mongodb, match, matching

I have a MongoDB (`v6.0.3`) document in my database:

```
{
  "user": "123",
  "alerts": [
    {
      "alertDirection": "$gte",
      "alertValue": 9999,
      "location": "home",
      "available": false,
      "position": 28
    },
    {
      "alertDirection": "$lte",
      "alertValue": 50,
      "location": "home",
      "available": true,
      "position": 14
    },
    {
      "alertDirection": "$gte",
      "alertValue": 100,
      "location": "home",
      "available": true,
      "position": 71
    },
    {
      "alertDirection": "$gte",
      "alertValue": 100,
      "location": "out",
      "available": true,
      "position": 43
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm matching array elements I need based on few conditions:

```
{
  $match: {
    "alerts": {
      $elemMatch: {
        $and: [
          { "location": "home" },
          { "available": true }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to expand my `$match` to fetch only documents with `alerts` elements matching `alertValue` based on `alertDirection` value and a variable I have?

For example, I have a variable `myValue` with value `10`. I'd like to match only elements in array where `myValue` is either higher or lower than `alertValue`, depending on `alertDirection`. In my example, the only match would be the following element (because `10` is `lower or equal` than `50`):

```
{
  "alertDirection": "$lte",
  "alertValue": 50,
  "location": "home",
  "available": true,
  "position": 14
}
```

Or if `myValue` would be `100`, only the following element would be matched (because `100` is `greater or equal` than `100`):

```
{
  "alertDirection": "$gte",
  "alertValue": 100,
  "location": "home",
  "available": true,
  "position": 71
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

The trick here is to use `$cond` and if the "direction" is `$gte` then compare with `$gte` otherwise `$lte` (but be careful to use `$literal` to get the string literal.

And the last step is a group to get result into an array in the same way that are into DB but is optional.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$alerts"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "alerts.location": "home",
      "alerts.available": true,
      "$expr": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": ["$alerts.alertDirection",{"$literal": "$gte"}]
          },
          "then": {"$gte": [yourValue,"$alerts.alertValue"]},
          "else": {"$lte": [yourValue,"$alerts.alertValue"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "user": {
        "$first": "$user"
      },
      "alerts": {
        "$push": "$alerts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BZY3LLelFyf)